# Находится ли элемент поверх другого js

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно выяснить поверх какого элемента находится элемент `dot` и вывести его `id`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var min = 0;
  var max = 300;
  var random = Math.random() * (+max - +min) + +min;
  $("#dot").css("left", random);
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
}

#dot {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block" id="3"></div>
<div class="block" id="1"></div>
<div class="block" id="2"></div>
<div id="dot"></div>
```

Comment: Если вы можете определить вершины каждого прямоугольника, то можно сравнить их координаты. В аналитической геометрии есть описание методов проверок на пересечение фигур. Для прямоугольников - левая верхняя вершина внутренней фигуры должна лежать правее и ниже левой верхней вершины внешней фигуры; правая верхняя вершина внутренней - левее и ниже соответствующей вершины внешней... и т.д.

Comment: @cauf я предполагаю это не самое правильное решение

Comment: C математической точки зрения - самое правильное. Все остальное - обертка над ним